# Finding an entire function such that $|f(z)| > e^{Im f(z)}$ and $f(0)=2$ & an analytic function that has an essential singularity at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, entire-functions

Here are my problems:

> 1. Find an entire function $f(z)$ such that $|f(z)| > e^{\operatorname{Im} f(z)}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f(0)=2$.

I am trying to guess $2\cos(z), 2e^z$, etc, but they are all failed in the end.

> 2. Let $f(z)$ be analytic in the punctured disk $0<|z|<1$, and $f(\frac 1n)=\sqrt{n}$ for every integer $n>1$. Prove that $f(z)$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$.

I am trying to use the definition of essential singularity to prove. But I don't know how to express the $f(z).$

Comment: @user9706: it is more typical on this website to ask separate questions *in separate questions*, unless the several parts of your questions are very closely related. I would suggest you keep this one question about the first of your two, edit the title to be more descriptive, and ask the second question in a separate thread. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think @Willie intended to say you should change this question *after someone has answered*, rather that you should ask separate questions separately, *next time*. With the new version, @user9325's answer didn't make much sense anymore, so I've rolled back to the last version.

Comment: @user9706: right, sorry about that. When I made that comment there were no answers posted. Please follow Theo's suggestion now.

Answer (score 8):

1. You ask a lot: $2=|f(0)|< e^{Im f(0)}=e^0=1$.
   (For the new version: Have you tried $e^z+e^{-z}$?)
2. It would be a better idea to show that the singularity is neither removable nor a pole and then use the classification of singularities.

Answer (score 3):

2) if there were a pole at zero
$$
f(z)=\sum_{k=-N}^{\infty}a_kz^k, N>0
$$
then $f(1/n)\sim a_{-N}n^N$ but the assumption is $f(1/n)\sim n^{1/2}$